# I can't save record in sqlite Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I try save record on database, in pivot table but I have a error(screen) if I write `@video.category_ids = 1` it works but category id = 1 in database

Below I put my code if you neeed more information please write.

videos_controller.rb

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController

  layout 'master'
  before_action :chceck_login

  def index
    @videos = Video.sortASC
  end

  def new
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def create
    @video = Video.new(video_params)
    @video.category_ids = [video_params]
    if @video.save
      flash[:notice] = 'The movie has been added successfuly'
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      @categories = Category.all
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def delete
  end

  private

  def video_params
    params.require(:video).permit(:title, :url, :description, category_attributes: [:id]).merge(user_id: session[:user_id])
  end

end
```

_form_html.erb

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-tag"></i></span>
  </div>
  <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: 'Title', :class => 'form-control', :id => 'title' %>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-link"></i></span>
  </div>
  <%= f.text_field :url, placeholder: 'URL', :class => 'form-control', :id => 'url' %>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></span>
  </div>
  <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: 'Description', rows: 5, :class => 'form-control', :id => 'description' %>
</div>

<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fas fa-sitemap"></i></span>
  </div>
  <%= f.select(:category_id, @categories.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {}, :multiple => true, :class => 'custom-select') %>
</div>
```

video.rb

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

  scope :sortASC, lambda{order("videos.created_at ASC")}

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<% @page_title = 'Add Film' %>

<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col s-6'>
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid bg-info">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4 text-center">ADD NEW FILM <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></h1>
          <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col s-6'>
      <%= form_for(:video, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
        <%= render(:partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => f}) %>
        <%= submit_tag('Add Film', :class => 'btn btn-primary float-right') %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Error 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqnfZ.jpg

If you want I have put my project on Github.

Comment: `video_params` is not a number, so `@video.category_ids = [video_params]` does not work. That's what the error is telling you,

Comment: So what i should write there, becouse how i write @video.category_ids = "request with form" it works but  value is empty and record don't save in pivot table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following changes:

1. In _form.html.erb pluralize the name of the select, i.e. change

   ```
   <%= f.select(:category_id, @categories.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {}, :multiple => true, :class => 'custom-select') %>
   ```

   to

   ```
   <%= f.select(:category_ids, @categories.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, {}, :multiple => true, :class => 'custom-select') %>
   ```
2. In videos_controller.rb change

   ```
   def video_params
     params.require(:video).permit(:title, :url, :description, category_attributes: [:id]).merge(user_id: session[:user_id])
   end
   ```

   to

   ```
   def video_params
     params[:video][:category_ids].reject!(&:blank?) unless params[:video][:category_ids].nil?
     params.require(:video).permit(:title, :url, :description, category_ids: []).merge(user_id: session[:user_id])
   end
   ```
3. Also in videos_controller.rb remove

   ```
   @video.category_ids = [video_params]
   ```

   to leave things to the constructor

Regarding 2. I am not 100% sure about the exact solution, maybe you should also reject the empty id you have in your parameters (according to the provided screenshot, use `.reject!(&:blank?)` for that) - for analyzing further problems check the output of the `video_params` function before passing it to the constructor - it basically should look like a hash representation of the expected object.

**edit** Updated the change proposal for 2. regarding category_ids

Comment: Thanks for your answer when i've made your changes there is no errors but record don't save in pvot table

Comment: Can you post what the function `video_params` returns?

Comment: {"title"=>"sdsd", "url"=>"sdsd", "description"=>"sdsd", "category_ids"=>["", "2", "3", "4"]} and what first record i array categoty_ids is empty ? mamy this is reason ?

Comment: When i chceck this array category_ids return [ ]

Comment: Updated the change proposal for `video_params`, see above